# Failed to sync gradle project (Unknown host 'services.gradle.org')

Tags: android, gradle, proxy, http-proxy

I have an error with `Gradle`, when I create a new project in `android studio`, I'm not experienced in `android` programming please help me,

see the http proxy error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and i tried the above solution (by Sathish Kumar J) but it didnt work.

if found the solution below at this link.
http://vjscrazzy.blogspot.co.il/2016/02/failed-to-sync-gradle-project.html

step 1

```
file>Setttings>appearance and behaviour>system setttings>HTTP proxy> set No Proxy
```

step 2

```
build,execution and deployment> Build tools > gradle>now under project level settings > select local gradle distribution>gradle home = F:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/gradle-2.4
```

NOTE:
 
in my case my default android studio .gradle folder is located in
"F:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/gradle-2.4"
change it with your defualt directory.

Answer (score 1):

> In **.gradle** folder open **gradle.properties** and clear proxies

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Go to..

**File** > **Settings** > **Appearance & Behavior** > **System Settings** > **HTTP Proxy** [Under IDE Settings] Enable following option **Auto-detect proxy settings**

you can also use the test connection button and check with google.com to see if it works or not.

Comment: hi, I have done this but it didn't work. Also I reinstalled the SDK and the android studio but it didn't work. But when I updated the SDK it worked properly! I really didn't know what was wrong...

Answer (score 0):

In case you're not behind a proxy and still getting this error: Gradle also has global settings - either there are some presets or you saved some proxy settings in the global gradle.properties file. Simply adjust the proxy settings in the global gradle.properties file to your needs. I simply removed the entries in that file since i'm usually not behind a proxy. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Go to gradle-wrapper.properties and update this gradle-7.2 to