# Gradle not syncing

Tags: android, android-studio

I just imported a project downloaded from Github but Gradle is not syncing, it is giving the error " Unknow host  'swervice.gradle.org'. You may need to adjust the proxy setting in Gradle "

[image]

I would appreciate any kind of help

Comment: Muhammad Ahsan Mukhtar please try below answer

Answer (score 1):

Go to..

File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > HTTP Proxy [Under IDE Settings] Enable following option Auto-detect proxy settings

On Mac it's under:

Android Studio > Preferences > Appearance & Behaviour... etc

Comment: @Muhammad Ahsan Mukhtar you can also look into this link for more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37275654/failed-to-sync-gradle-project-unknown-host-services-gradle-org .If its working then please approved it as a answer

Answer (score 0):

First don't import it !
Beacuse the project maybe use another Gradle Version or use another Sdk

The best Way is Copy and Past java layout and etc from current project that you Download it to new Project.

Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have your HTTP Proxy details, you can chose No proxy, It will bypass the proxy settings and us the settings on your system. It worked for me

File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > HTTP Proxy [Select No Proxy]